# Python syntax for an empty while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I have written this:

```
    while file.readline().startswith("#"):
        continue
```

But I suspect the `continue` is unnecessary? What is the correct syntax for what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: When I do this sort of thing I have a generator that skips commented lines and just yields the good lines. Whereas your use case seems to be for skipping the comments at the head of a file.

Comment: In this simple example pass and continue are equivalent. I'd favour continue however as it expresses your intent more clearly.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
while file.readline().startswith("#"):
    pass
```

This uses the pass statement :

> The pass statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/passStatements.html

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer link to `pass` statement tutorial is no longer working see official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

> pass is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed