# IndentationError: expected an indented block, but it seems correct

Tags: python, indentation

In the code I provided there is an

```
>IndentationError in line 10, or at the END of:

> while ((while_bolian == "") and (correct_count >= 0) and (total_count != 0)) or ((while_bolian == True) and (correct_count >= 0) and (total_count != 0)):
```

However all my indentations seem correct, I am using pycharm and if I put my cursor just after the above line of code it says `Indent Expected`.

I have done research about this error however nothing seems to be helping with the problem.

```
    total_count = int(input("how many questions do you want to be in the quizz \n10.\n50.\n100.\n:"))
    try:
        while ((while_bolian == "") and (correct_count >= 0) and (total_count != 0)) or ((while_bolian == True) and (correct_count >= 0) and (total_count != 0)):
    except ValueError:
        print("please enter a question limit")

>     line 10
        except ValueError:
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you add a tag for the language you are using? You might find better help by specifying what language this is coded in.

Comment: Except has to be same indent as try

Comment: yea, sorry that was just copped into the web-sight incorrectly in the script editor it is in the same indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The while need an instruction like `pass`, with an extra indentation.
Right now the `while` tries to run the `except`!
See for example [Python syntax for an empty while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797046/python-syntax-for-an-empty-while-loop)